# Calculating the 0.50 delta strike

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

According to most books the ATM option is the option with a delta of 0.50. However, this is only the case when the distribution is normal. The more positively skewed the distribution, the further the 0.50 delta option is out-of-the-money (for calls). According to the following [article](https://moontowermeta.com/lessons-from-the-50-delta-option/), the formula to calculate the 0.50 delta option strike is equal to:

```
S x e^(σ^2/2)
```

I want to know why this is exactly the case. Looking at the delta defintion I have:

```
delta = N(d1) = 0.50
```

Therefore,

```
d1 = 0
```

And

[image: href="https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=d1&space;=&space;\frac{ln(\frac{S}{K})+(r+\frac{^{\sigma^{2}}}{2})T}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}]

So, how do I get from this well-known formula to the above mentioned formula? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

The delta you mentioned is the Black-Scholes delta. If you let $r=0$, $T=1$ and solve the equation $d_1=0$, you get what is in the article.

Comment: $0=\frac{\ln(S/K)+(0+\sigma^2/2)*1}{\sigma*1}$ gives $0=\ln(S/K)+\sigma^2/2$ gives $-\ln(S/K)=\sigma^2/2$ gives $S/K=e^{-0.5 \sigma^2}$ finally gives $K=S e^{0.5\sigma^2}$

Answer (score 2):

As you point out in your d1 formula:

$$d_1 = \frac{ln \left( \frac{S}{K} \right)+\left(r+0.5\sigma^2 \right)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}} $$

Therefore, $N(d_1)$ (where $N(.)$ stands for the Standard Normal CDF) is only equal to half when $d_1$ is exactly zero. When an option is ATM, then $S=Ke^{-rT}$. So $N(d_1)$ won't be exactly 0.5, because:

$$d_1 = 0.5\sigma\sqrt(T)$$

For short dated options, $N(d_1)$ of the above will be close to 0.5, whilst for longer-dated options (like 10-year expiry) it will be higher than 0.5.

Indeed, if you set: $S=Ke^\left(-0.5\sigma^2T-rT \right)$, you will set $d_1$ to zero.

People who say that:

**(i) $N(d_1)$ for ATM options is exactly half**

**(ii) ATM option has $N(d_2)$ equal to half because $N(d_2)$ is the probability that the option will end up in the money**

Are (in my experience) mostly option traders who lack the technical knowledge to understand how option pricing works. $N(d_2)$ is the **risk-neutral** probability, so has nothing to do with "likelihood" or "real-world probability" as we humans like to interpret probability. "Risk-neutral" probability is a mathematical construct invented for pricing options.

Comment: $N(d_1)$ is not the standard risk neutral probability of the event $\{S_T\geq K\}$ though. This is $N(d_2)$. You need a change of numeraire. $N(d_1)$ correspond to the exercise probability under the stock measure which uses $S_t$ or $S_te^{qt}$ as numeraire.

Comment: @KeChen: you're totally right, careless mistake.